# How to validate chinese email in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, validation

I want to validate both english and chinese language in my project which use angularjs and php.

```
<form name="form" class="form-validation">
    <div class="mail">
        <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" placeholder="Email 邮箱" required >

        <span class="errMsg" ng-show="form.email.$touched && form.email.$invalid">Please enter valid email address</span>

    </div>
    <div class="enter">
        <button data-ng-click="enter()" name="register" >
            <img src="public/img/enter.png" alt="" width="100%">
        </button>

    </div>

</form>
```

I have searched in google and i came to know that it can be done with regex.but i don't know anything about it and don't know from where to start.

edited...

```
<input type="email" ng-model="email" ng-pattern="/^(?!\.)((?!.*\.{2})[a-zA-Z0-9\x{0080}-\x{00FF}\x{0100}-\x{017F}\x{0180}-\x{024F}\x{0250}-\x{02AF}\x{0300}-\x{036F}\x{0370}-\x{03FF}\x{0400}-\x{04FF}\x{0500}-\x{052F}\x{0530}-\x{058F}\x{0590}-\x{05FF}\x{0600}-\x{06FF}\x{0700}-\x{074F}\x{0750}-\x{077F}\x{0780}-\x{07BF}\x{07C0}-\x{07FF}\x{0900}-\x{097F}\x{0980}-\x{09FF}\x{0A00}-\x{0A7F}\x{0A80}-\x{0AFF}\x{0B00}-\x{0B7F}\x{0B80}-\x{0BFF}\x{0C00}-\x{0C7F}\x{0C80}-\x{0CFF}\x{0D00}-\x{0D7F}\x{0D80}-\x{0DFF}\x{0E00}-\x{0E7F}\x{0E80}-\x{0EFF}\x{0F00}-\x{0FFF}\x{1000}-\x{109F}\x{10A0}-\x{10FF}\x{1100}-\x{11FF}\x{1200}-\x{137F}\x{1380}-\x{139F}\x{13A0}-\x{13FF}\x{1400}-\x{167F}\x{1680}-\x{169F}\x{16A0}-\x{16FF}\x{1700}-\x{171F}\x{1720}-\x{173F}\x{1740}-\x{175F}\x{1760}-\x{177F}\x{1780}-\x{17FF}\x{1800}-\x{18AF}\x{1900}-\x{194F}\x{1950}-\x{197F}\x{1980}-\x{19DF}\x{19E0}-\x{19FF}\x{1A00}-\x{1A1F}\x{1B00}-\x{1B7F}\x{1D00}-\x{1D7F}\x{1D80}-\x{1DBF}\x{1DC0}-\x{1DFF}\x{1E00}-\x{1EFF}\x{1F00}-\x{1FFF}\x{20D0}-\x{20FF}\x{2100}-\x{214F}\x{2C00}-\x{2C5F}\x{2C60}-\x{2C7F}\x{2C80}-\x{2CFF}\x{2D00}-\x{2D2F}\x{2D30}-\x{2D7F}\x{2D80}-\x{2DDF}\x{2F00}-\x{2FDF}\x{2FF0}-\x{2FFF}\x{3040}-\x{309F}\x{30A0}-\x{30FF}\x{3100}-\x{312F}\x{3130}-\x{318F}\x{3190}-\x{319F}\x{31C0}-\x{31EF}\x{31F0}-\x{31FF}\x{3200}-\x{32FF}\x{3300}-\x{33FF}\x{3400}-\x{4DBF}\x{4DC0}-\x{4DFF}\x{4E00}-\x{9FFF}\x{A000}-\x{A48F}\x{A490}-\x{A4CF}\x{A700}-\x{A71F}\x{A800}-\x{A82F}\x{A840}-\x{A87F}\x{AC00}-\x{D7AF}\x{F900}-\x{FAFF}\.!#$%&'*+-\/=?^_`{|}~\-\d]+)@(?!\.)([a-zA-Z0-9\x{0080}-\x{00FF}\x{0100}-\x{017F}\x{0180}-\x{024F}\x{0250}-\x{02AF}\x{0300}-\x{036F}\x{0370}-\x{03FF}\x{0400}-\x{04FF}\x{0500}-\x{052F}\x{0530}-\x{058F}\x{0590}-\x{05FF}\x{0600}-\x{06FF}\x{0700}-\x{074F}\x{0750}-\x{077F}\x{0780}-\x{07BF}\x{07C0}-\x{07FF}\x{0900}-\x{097F}\x{0980}-\x{09FF}\x{0A00}-\x{0A7F}\x{0A80}-\x{0AFF}\x{0B00}-\x{0B7F}\x{0B80}-\x{0BFF}\x{0C00}-\x{0C7F}\x{0C80}-\x{0CFF}\x{0D00}-\x{0D7F}\x{0D80}-\x{0DFF}\x{0E00}-\x{0E7F}\x{0E80}-\x{0EFF}\x{0F00}-\x{0FFF}\x{1000}-\x{109F}\x{10A0}-\x{10FF}\x{1100}-\x{11FF}\x{1200}-\x{137F}\x{1380}-\x{139F}\x{13A0}-\x{13FF}\x{1400}-\x{167F}\x{1680}-\x{169F}\x{16A0}-\x{16FF}\x{1700}-\x{171F}\x{1720}-\x{173F}\x{1740}-\x{175F}\x{1760}-\x{177F}\x{1780}-\x{17FF}\x{1800}-\x{18AF}\x{1900}-\x{194F}\x{1950}-\x{197F}\x{1980}-\x{19DF}\x{19E0}-\x{19FF}\x{1A00}-\x{1A1F}\x{1B00}-\x{1B7F}\x{1D00}-\x{1D7F}\x{1D80}-\x{1DBF}\x{1DC0}-\x{1DFF}\x{1E00}-\x{1EFF}\x{1F00}-\x{1FFF}\x{20D0}-\x{20FF}\x{2100}-\x{214F}\x{2C00}-\x{2C5F}\x{2C60}-\x{2C7F}\x{2C80}-\x{2CFF}\x{2D00}-\x{2D2F}\x{2D30}-\x{2D7F}\x{2D80}-\x{2DDF}\x{2F00}-\x{2FDF}\x{2FF0}-\x{2FFF}\x{3040}-\x{309F}\x{30A0}-\x{30FF}\x{3100}-\x{312F}\x{3130}-\x{318F}\x{3190}-\x{319F}\x{31C0}-\x{31EF}\x{31F0}-\x{31FF}\x{3200}-\x{32FF}\x{3300}-\x{33FF}\x{3400}-\x{4DBF}\x{4DC0}-\x{4DFF}\x{4E00}-\x{9FFF}\x{A000}-\x{A48F}\x{A490}-\x{A4CF}\x{A700}-\x{A71F}\x{A800}-\x{A82F}\x{A840}-\x{A87F}\x{AC00}-\x{D7AF}\x{F900}-\x{FAFF}\-\.\d]+)((\.([a-zA-Z\x{0080}-\x{00FF}\x{0100}-\x{017F}\x{0180}-\x{024F}\x{0250}-\x{02AF}\x{0300}-\x{036F}\x{0370}-\x{03FF}\x{0400}-\x{04FF}\x{0500}-\x{052F}\x{0530}-\x{058F}\x{0590}-\x{05FF}\x{0600}-\x{06FF}\x{0700}-\x{074F}\x{0750}-\x{077F}\x{0780}-\x{07BF}\x{07C0}-\x{07FF}\x{0900}-\x{097F}\x{0980}-\x{09FF}\x{0A00}-\x{0A7F}\x{0A80}-\x{0AFF}\x{0B00}-\x{0B7F}\x{0B80}-\x{0BFF}\x{0C00}-\x{0C7F}\x{0C80}-\x{0CFF}\x{0D00}-\x{0D7F}\x{0D80}-\x{0DFF}\x{0E00}-\x{0E7F}\x{0E80}-\x{0EFF}\x{0F00}-\x{0FFF}\x{1000}-\x{109F}\x{10A0}-\x{10FF}\x{1100}-\x{11FF}\x{1200}-\x{137F}\x{1380}-\x{139F}\x{13A0}-\x{13FF}\x{1400}-\x{167F}\x{1680}-\x{169F}\x{16A0}-\x{16FF}\x{1700}-\x{171F}\x{1720}-\x{173F}\x{1740}-\x{175F}\x{1760}-\x{177F}\x{1780}-\x{17FF}\x{1800}-\x{18AF}\x{1900}-\x{194F}\x{1950}-\x{197F}\x{1980}-\x{19DF}\x{19E0}-\x{19FF}\x{1A00}-\x{1A1F}\x{1B00}-\x{1B7F}\x{1D00}-\x{1D7F}\x{1D80}-\x{1DBF}\x{1DC0}-\x{1DFF}\x{1E00}-\x{1EFF}\x{1F00}-\x{1FFF}\x{20D0}-\x{20FF}\x{2100}-\x{214F}\x{2C00}-\x{2C5F}\x{2C60}-\x{2C7F}\x{2C80}-\x{2CFF}\x{2D00}-\x{2D2F}\x{2D30}-\x{2D7F}\x{2D80}-\x{2DDF}\x{2F00}-\x{2FDF}\x{2FF0}-\x{2FFF}\x{3040}-\x{309F}\x{30A0}-\x{30FF}\x{3100}-\x{312F}\x{3130}-\x{318F}\x{3190}-\x{319F}\x{31C0}-\x{31EF}\x{31F0}-\x{31FF}\x{3200}-\x{32FF}\x{3300}-\x{33FF}\x{3400}-\x{4DBF}\x{4DC0}-\x{4DFF}\x{4E00}-\x{9FFF}\x{A000}-\x{A48F}\x{A490}-\x{A4CF}\x{A700}-\x{A71F}\x{A800}-\x{A82F}\x{A840}-\x{A87F}\x{AC00}-\x{D7AF}\x{F900}-\x{FAFF}]){2,63})+)$/u">
```

Comment: there may be regex, but can be with 10k long, you still need to do confirmation email to validate the ownership, so better accept everything that looks like email and then verify with confirmation email is more realistic, imo.

Comment: i used angular ng-pattern for validation but it won't work for me

Comment: i think ng-pattern don't need `/ .. /` to wrap regex, and `/u` is not valid javascript regex flag, imo.

Comment: also you need `novalidate` directive on form tag to prevent html5 form validation, i think.

Comment: i want to register an chinese email in our database and login with that email address, can you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern

```
/^[-_0-9a-z\u4e00-\u9fbf]+$/i
```

Comment: can you elaborate with an explanation how this might help ?

Comment: use the patten above as the javascript REG_EXP, then test the word weather matching the pattern.